# Disable initial animation state in css?

Tags: css-transitions

Say I have a button like this:

```
<button>Some Text</button>
```

And by default the stylesheet has the text as black.

I then have this css:

```
button {
     transition: color 0.15s ease-out;
     color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}

button:hover {
     transition: color 0.15s ease-out;
     color: #fff;
}
```

The goal is to subtly fade from a grayish off-white, to white, on hover, and then back again to normal button appearance on hover off.

The problem is when i firstly load the page, the black initial color of button is overwritten by the transition that i applied on button, and one can briefly see black text fading to off-white.

How do I make it so that the initial state just loads without animation? Or more precisely, is there a way to achieve something like `:hover-off` to control the animation only when the hover state turns off?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i have less reputation to comment. Your animation does not work, please explain clearly what you want to do?

are you trying to achieve this.

```
button:hover {
transition: 0.5s ease-out;
color : white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to load some JavaScript, you can put it in the `<head>` *after* your CSS. Kind of a hack, but it works.

HTML parsing is blocked by `<script>` tags that initiate requests for external resources. I guess CSS animations won't start until the `<body>` has been fully parsed and that's the reason this works.